# ProgressBar in ActionBar appcompat

Tags: android

I am trying to use appcompat in my application. But ProgressBar in ActionBar very big. How I can do ProgressBar less?

http://itmages.ru/image/view/1451590/2f1dfa13

code manifest

```
<activity
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:name="com.example.ok1.MainActivity"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" 
 android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: You can change the size of progressbar

Comment: what are you using ActionbarSherlock ??

Comment: I am using appcompat, How I can change size?

Comment: Write me please example

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/abc_action_button_min_width">

   <ProgressBar
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
       android:layout_width="32dp"
       android:layout_height="32dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This may help you..

Answer (score 3):

Please use style in progressbar

```
<ProgressBar 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall" />
```

Comment: Prefixing it with `android:` won't load the AppCompat variant, right?